# How should I know the node version to use for a React.js project, if it's not documented anywhere?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I have ran to an old project and I didn't document which node version I should use, luckily I remembered the correct version, and of course it's a bad practice not to document it.

However, it came to my mind what if I came to a project that didn't has it documented as well how should I know which node version to use ?

Comment: What is your project's React version?

Comment: You can check the last commit history and cross reference with node version release dates and get a node version that was stable at the time of the commit most probably it will work .
The scenario however is quite unlikely as the internet is not full of code snippets that are hard to track for ownership and responsibility

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.
But, you could track the versions of the npm packages used, get the date/compatibility rate with node versions. All of that is manual work propaply.
So if you were looking for some `whatnodeversion "/path_to_project"`, it doesn't exists.